# A set of possibly linearly independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set of functions $\{f_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, i\in \mathbb{N}\ | \ f_i(x)=|x-i| \}$  linearly independent?

The functions are defined over the real numbers and $i$ is a natural number.

Comment: what? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: By "fi(x)=/x-i/", do you mean $f_i(x) = x-i$ or $f_i(x) = |x-i|$, or something else?

Comment: fi(x) is the absolute value of x-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: any nontrivial linear combination is non-differentiable ....